# Google's Safe Browsing malware flag and Bit.ly custom domains

Tags: security, bit.ly, malware-detection, safe-browsing

I'm trying to better understand how to implement a custom domain with `bit.ly` without getting flagged by [Google's Safe Browsing Site Status](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/?hl=en).

As I understand it, you can get flagged by Google if you have a link on your site to another site that has already been flagged by Google.

How does this work if you are using your domain for shortening URLs?

Bitly, for example, is flagged as "potentially dangerous" by Google but not "Dangerous", therefore the domain is not added to the [browser malware blacklist](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?hl=en). Bitly is able to have links to sites flagged as "Dangerous" without being blacklisted, but custom domains receive the "Dangerous" flag if the same incident occurs.

Is there a way to implement a custom domain with `bit.ly` without the risk of getting blacklisted by Google if a site you are linking to is flagged as "Dangerous"?

[Screenshot 1 - Site not flagged by Google's Safe Browsing Site Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FTJh.png)

[Screenshot 2 - Site flagged as partially dangerous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y098s.png)

[Screenshot 3 - Site flagged as dangerous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLtjD.png)